# Slicing a dataframe on column names or alternative column name if they are not available

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am looking for a way to eliminate key errors that are caused by different  column names in the data that gets loaded. So for example I might have columns like

```
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 2)), columns=['Test','Test_v2'])

     Test  Test_v2
0     0        3
1     0        0
2     1        2
3     4        0
4     4        4
```

How can I do s.th. like

```
dummy_df[ if_avail('Test') otherwise 'Test_v2']
```

It would be nice to be able passing a list, where it starts checking for existence in item order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can check columns names and select first matched column:

```
L = ['Test_v1','Test','Test_v2']

m = dummy_df.columns.isin(L)
first = dummy_df.columns[m].values[0]

s = dummy_df[first]
print (s)
0    3
1    2
2    3
3    0
4    0
Name: Test, dtype: int32
```

Another solution is:

```
print (dummy_df.reindex(columns=L).dropna(axis=1, how='all').iloc[:, 0])
0    3
1    2
2    3
3    0
4    0
Name: Test, dtype: int32
```

**Explanation**:

First reindex by list of columns names:

```
print (dummy_df.reindex(columns=L))
   Test_v1  Test  Test_v2
0      NaN     3        2
1      NaN     2        3
2      NaN     3        1
3      NaN     0        0
4      NaN     0        2
```

And remove all columns with all NaNs:

```
print (dummy_df.reindex(columns=L).dropna(axis=1, how='all'))
   Test  Test_v2
0     3        2
1     2        3
2     3        1
3     0        0
4     0        2
```

And last select first column by `iloc`:

```
print (dummy_df.reindex(columns=L).dropna(axis=1, how='all').iloc[:, 0])0    3
1    2
2    3
3    0
4    0
Name: Test, dtype: int32
```